# Range space of Similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

Do similar matrices share the same column space $Colsp$ and null space $Nullsp$?

**What I think !:** If $A$ and $B$ are two similar matrices then they must have same range space and null space i.e. $Colsp(A)=Colsp(B)$ and consequently by rank-nullity theorem, we have $Nullsp(A)=Nullsp(B)$ . 
I am unable to conclude the answer. Please help!!.

Comment: Have you tried making up a small example, and seeing what happens?

Comment: Note that if $A$ is invertible, then so is any matrix similar to $A$, thus with trivial null space & full column space, so the example to look at is one that's not invertible.

Comment: I have taken A= [ 1 0 ; 0 0]  and B= [0 0; 0 1], these are similar 2x2 matrices . but range space of A and B are different. That is why I got confused. A and B both are representing same transformation then they should have same range space and null space. I want to understand why this is happening ?

Comment: They represent the same transformation, but with respect to different bases. So the null space, and the column space, also look different with respect to different bases.

Comment: That means if in general we talk about column space and null space of any linear transformation, then it is corresponding to *standard bases* only? e.g. If  T(x, y)=(x,0) then the range space is x axis on xy-plane and null space is y axis on xy-plane (when the transformation is considered with respect to the standard bases).

Comment: do the range space and column space of a transformation vary according to the choice of the bases, and hence not unique?

Comment: Those spaces do not depend on the choice of basis, but the way we represent them does.